# Styling SVG Fill Color of an input element

Tags: css, svg

Is it possible to change the Fill Color of the SVG content when the input element below is in :hover state **without changing** the source svg image?

```
<input type="image" src="images/toolbar/check.svg" />
```

The solution that ultimately worked is based on Erik's suggestion:

First the input element needs to be changed into a button element with inline svg content:

```
<button type="button">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"     version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 95.453 100" enable-background="new 0 0 95.453 100" xml:space="preserve"><g><g><polygon points="94.587,27.48 31.657,86.15 31.217,85.68 18.847,72.41 0.566,52.81 14.106,40.19 32.387,59.79 81.776,13.74"/></g></g>
</svg>
</button>
```

Then we can style the svg fill color using ordinary CSS:

```
button:hover svg {
    fill: red;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use inline svg for this instead, and then add some CSS to style the fill colors. That should be more efficient.