# Changing fill color in svg in an input type image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm following this example:
[img src SVG changing the fill color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933430/img-src-svg-changing-the-fill-color)

To change an input label like this:

```
<input name="ctl00$ctl00$cphM$cph$ImageButtonAnadirLote" class="btnAfirmativo" id="ctl00_ctl00_cphM_cph_ImageButtonAnadirLote" style="border-width: 0px; cursor: pointer;" onclick='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ctl00$cphM$cph$ImageButtonAnadirLote", "", true, "", "", false, false))' type="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Windows_logo_-_2012_%28red%29.svg">
```

Where the CSS is:

```
btnAfirmativo{width: 350px; height: 350px;}
btnAfirmativo path {fill: #000 !important;}
```

To change the color of a svg refereed by a input type image. I tried to adapt the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/kurnosem/fucdt3fp/2/

There is another question: [Styling SVG Fill Color of an input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520915/styling-svg-fill-color-of-an-input-element)
But this one does not offer the solution that I want.

Is it possible to change the color of an input tag type image if the image is a svg file? (adapting the jsfiddle code)

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot style a remote resource - only inline SVG can be styled. You can achieve a similar result, however, by using `filter: brightness(0);` on your input if, and only if, it's just your image, with no background or other visual styles whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already open the SVG and manipulate its content, you can do so with its fill color as well.

```
var $path = jQuery(data).find('path');
$path.attr('style', $path.attr('style').replace("#e81123","#000"));
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fucdt3fp/12/)

Stack snippet

```js
$(function(){
  //jQuery('img.btnAfirmativo').each(function(){
    jQuery('input.btnAfirmativo').each(function(){
        var $img = jQuery(this);
        var imgID = $img.attr('id');
        var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
        var imgURL = $img.attr('src');
        
    jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
        
            var $path = jQuery(data).find('path');
            $path.attr('style', $path.attr('style').replace("#e81123","#000"));

            // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
            var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');
            
            // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
            if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
                $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
            }
            // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
            if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
            }
    
            // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
            $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');
            
            // Check if the viewport is set, else we gonna set it if we can.
            if(!$svg.attr('viewBox') && $svg.attr('height') && $svg.attr('width')) {
                $svg.attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + $svg.attr('height') + ' ' + $svg.attr('width'))
            }
    
            // Replace image with new SVG
            $img.replaceWith($svg);
    
        }, 'xml');
    
    });
});
```

```css
btnAfirmativo{width: 350px; height: 350px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="btnAfirmativo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Windows_logo_-_2012_%28red%29.svg" alt="Microsoft" width="350" height="350">
<input name="ctl00$ctl00$cphM$cph$ImageButtonAnadirLote" class="btnAfirmativo" id="ctl00_ctl00_cphM_cph_ImageButtonAnadirLote" style="border-width: 0px; cursor: pointer;" onclick='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ctl00$cphM$cph$ImageButtonAnadirLote", "", true, "", "", false, false))' type="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Windows_logo_-_2012_%28red%29.svg">
```

---

With CSS, update it to this

```
.btnAfirmativo{width: 350px; height: 350px;}
.btnAfirmativo + svg path {fill: #0f0 !important;}
```

Stack snippet

```js
$(function(){
  //jQuery('img.btnAfirmativo').each(function(){
    jQuery('input.btnAfirmativo').each(function(){
        var $img = jQuery(this);
        var imgID = $img.attr('id');
        var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
        var imgURL = $img.attr('src');
        
    jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {        

            // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
            var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');
            
            // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
            if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
                $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
            }
            // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
            if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
            }
    
            // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
            $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');
            
            // Check if the viewport is set, else we gonna set it if we can.
            if(!$svg.attr('viewBox') && $svg.attr('height') && $svg.attr('width')) {
                $svg.attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + $svg.attr('height') + ' ' + $svg.attr('width'))
            }
    
            // Replace image with new SVG
            $img.replaceWith($svg);
    
        }, 'xml');
    
    });
});
```

```css
.btnAfirmativo{width: 350px; height: 350px;}
.btnAfirmativo + svg path {fill: #0f0 !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="btnAfirmativo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Windows_logo_-_2012_%28red%29.svg" alt="Microsoft" width="350" height="350">

<input name="ctl00$ctl00$cphM$cph$ImageButtonAnadirLote" class="btnAfirmativo" id="ctl00_ctl00_cphM_cph_ImageButtonAnadirLote" style="border-width: 0px; cursor: pointer;" onclick='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ctl00$cphM$cph$ImageButtonAnadirLote", "", true, "", "", false, false))' type="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Windows_logo_-_2012_%28red%29.svg">
```

Comment: Thanks! It was really helpful! But... one more question, why it doesn't work with this image: http://svgur.com/i/5xL.svg I tried to modify it here: http://jsfiddle.net/kurnosem/fucdt3fp/28/

Comment: @rasputino Without testing, I think it is because of their different `encoding`, where the first has `encoding="UTF-8"` and the second `encoding="iso-8859-1"`. If you check their initial `<?xml ... ?>` tag, you'll see they differ.

Comment: The problem is that the svg format can't be changed. I need to use an iso-8859-1 encoded svg file. There is any way to make it work? Thanks again

Comment: @rasputino If you compare the 2 svg file's `<xml>` and `<svg>` elements, you'll see their attributes differs. Try use the one's from the SVG that work in the one that doesn't, beside the `encoding`.

Comment: @rasputino One other thing I noticed now, is with the non-working SVG, the console reports _"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"_. Have you tried to copy the file to your own server/pc?